# How long does it take for the slime mold network model from netlogo to finish finding the shortest path?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to simulate the behavior of the slime mold Physarum Polycephalum using Netlogos slime mold network model. I have let the model run for 6 hours in hopes of finding the shortest path but it has yet to produce it.

I have left the model going for 6 hours as I thought that would be enough but the network til keeps changing and has not produced the shortest path.